# Tensor Product Rules

Tags: tensor-products, tensors, continuum-theory

I've just started a new term of uni and I just started a module in continuum mechanics, this being said there's some things that seem pretty important that I'm new to. The first exercise in the notes states to show various results regarding tensor product algebra, namely the first one being S(a ⊗ b) = (Sa) ⊗ b with a,b$\in{V}$ and S$\in{V^2}$ (We collect all vectors in the set V which forms a vector space over $\mathbb{R}$). Here's what I gather I can try to do to solve the equation from my notes:

As a,b$\in{V}$, we can write in a coordinate frame {e$^1$, e$^2$, e$^3$} that a=$\sum_{i=1}^3a_ie^i$ and b=$\sum_{i=1}^3b_ie^i$ and S can be written as a (3x3) matrix S$_{i,j}$, using this I assume we can separate out the equation S(a ⊗ b) = (Sa) ⊗ b, however our notes define the tensor product (a ⊗ b)v = (b · v)a  ∀v∈V. I'm quite confused as to what the tensor product even is and how one applies it to two vectors, or how I can solve questions like this rigorously using a coordinate frame which I believe the exercise is asking me to do.

Comment: Apparently, $V=\mathbb R^3\,.$ You should look up in Wikipedia what the Kronecker product is for two vectors $a,b\in\mathbb R^3\,.$ Then you will realize that $S(a\otimes b)=(Sa)\otimes b$ is just a matter of simple matrix multiplication. I am baffled that the person lecturing continuum mechanics doesn't mention that.

Comment: @KurtG. Well I haven't had a lecture in it yet, I'm sure it might be a case of me not understanding the notes properly. Thank you for your help however the page you alluded to states that the Kronecker product is a particular type of tensor product however my lecture notes don't mention such products once, would what you mentioned was true for Kronecker products be the same for all tensor products as well?

Comment: We don't need lectures to write out what $a\otimes b$ is when $a,b$ are two $3$-vectors. Follow the first formula [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product). It is *simplest* linear algebra. Having said that: some like to introduce tensors more abstractly but you can ignore that for now.

Comment: @KurtG. I see, I am however still confused, from what I've seen from the site that you linked I deduced that (a ⊗ b) is a 1x9 vector as a and b are both 1x3, however when S is a 3x3 matrix I can't multiply hence I can't find an answer. It seems like I'm going wrong with the dimensions of the vectors a and b however I'm confused why they would both be anything but 1x3 or 3x1 vectors which both lead to incorrect dimensions.

Comment: No. $a\otimes b=\begin{pmatrix}a_1b_1&a_1b_2&a_1b_3\\a_2b_1&a_2b_2&a_2b_3\\a_3b_1&a_3b_2&a_3b_3\end{pmatrix}\,.$